# How to organize duplicated buttons on different sections

Tags: usability, webforms

I have small window for applying different filters, each filter type has its section and its buttons. For me repeating the same buttons in a small sapce is confusing and unnecessary, what is the best UX design for this filter screen ?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Don't repeat the buttons.**

I see a little bit of content behind your filter panel, which means it's a popover vs. a fixed panel off to the side. So you'll want to allow your users to clear each filter section (like resetting all the checkboxes, or clearing out a text input) and to cancel out of the whole filtering experience (with a Cancel or X button), but there should only be one Apply button on a panel like this. Apply should close the panel and allow the user to see the filtered content.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding what probably confuses your users are checkboxes. I've fixed this issue in a couple of projects by converting long list of checkboxes into interactable badges. It saves space by making a list way shorter, it usually fits 2-3 badges per row depending on the label width.

[image]

[Source.](https://medium.com/tripaneer-techblog/improving-the-usability-of-multi-selecting-from-a-long-list-63e1a67aab35)

Other insights:

- The gap between reset and apply buttons should be consistent